# Azure Logic App gives 404 when trying to delete entity from Azure Table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Table that has a Partition Key of 'myPartition' and a 'Row Key' which contains an email address.

I am using an Azure Logic App to monitor a shared mailbox for subscribe messages, and then adding them to this table. This works fine.

However, when I get an unsubscribe message, and the Logic App tries to delete the entity using the Partition Key and Row Key, I get a 404 error, ResourceNotFound.

I can see that the row I am trying to delete is present, using Azure Storage Explorer.

I suspect that the issue may be caused by the @ character in the email address in the Row Key, as I have found articles that suggest certain characters are not valid in a Row Key - although none of them mention the @ character.

Can anybody offer any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the strings are _exactly_ the same? No spaces or casing differences?

Comment: Could you share your Logic Apps running Delete Entity Inputs? The @ character will be transform  to %40, and I test it won't matter the Delete Entity action.

Comment: Could you please share your logic app code ?

Comment: Did you find the answer or workaround ? I have similar issue with `:` as I am using timestamp as Key..

Answer (score 0):

The `@` character shouldn't be the issue:

> **Characters Disallowed in Key Fields**
>   The following characters are not allowed in values for the PartitionKey and RowKey properties:
>
> - The forward slash (/) character
> - The backslash (\) character
> - The number sign (#) character
> - The question mark (?) character
> - Control characters from U+0000 to U+001F, including:
>
>   - The horizontal tab (\t) character
>   - The linefeed (\n) character
>   - The carriage return (\r) character
> - Control characters from U+007F to U+009F

And

> The second part of the primary key is the row key, specified by the RowKey property. The row key is a unique identifier for an entity within a given partition. Together the PartitionKey and RowKey uniquely identify every entity within a table.
>
> The row key is a string value that may be up to 1 KB in size.
>
> You must include the RowKey property in every insert, update, and delete operation.

Taken from [Understanding the Table Service Data Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Understanding-the-Table-Service-Data-Model).

Are you *absolutely sure* the strings are exactly the same? No spaces or casing differences?